# VS Code: cspell checker stopped working, getting 'command resulted in as an error, command not found'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, command, spell-checking

I used Code Spell Checker in VS Code for many months, and it's stopped working. I'm using 'Code Spell Checker' and 'Polish - Code Spell Checker'. I tried uninstall , reload extensions, tried with only the default english one (Code Spell Checker) and also restart vscode. Nothings helps. When I try using Command Panel with any commands from 'CSpell Checker' this is what I get:

[Command '...' resulted in an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFyS9.png)

examples of the used commands:

- Spell: Enable Spell Checking by Default => Command 'Spell: Enable Spell Checking by Default' resulted in an error (command 'cSpell.enableForGlobal' not found)
- Spell: Create a CSpell Configuration File => Command 'Spell: Create a CSpell Configuration File.' resulted in an error (command 'cSpell.createCSpellConfig' not found)
- Spell: Show Spell Checker Configuration Info => (Command 'Spell: Show Spell Checker Configuration Info' resulted in an error (command 'cSpell.displayCSpellInfo' not found)

Comment: _" I tried uninstall, reload"_. If it's not working then try to reinstall both vscode and extension.

Comment: I don't want to lose my settings (colors, keyboard, settings, ...), I'm on mac. I wanted to left reinstalling vscode as absolute last option.

Comment: If you want to keep your then copy everything from the setting.json file. GOTO settings and on the top right-hand corner there is an execute button on right to it there is a logo when you hover on it shoes `settings.json` YOu need to copy everything from inside of it and save it to another file. Reinstall your vscode and login with the same id and then go to the settings.json file again and paste the data you copy here.  **I think If you log in with the same id then your settings will be reversed back But in case you have to copy data from the file**

Comment: @SharimIqbal thx, for answer :)  not every option is saved in setting.json, for example my custom keyboards shortcuts. Also needs to remember about 2 kinds of settings: workspace and user. 

For now, i installed additional newer version of vscode. Lost my custom colors for the theme, got new issue (error loading webview) ;) , but the settings, keyboards stayed the same and my extensions now works.

Comment: I had the same issue. I was running version 1.64.
After updating to the latest version, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

In my case both reinstalling the extension and VSCode didn't work. Here's what worked for me:

1. In VSCode, press `fn + F1`
2. Search for `Developer: Reinstall Extension...`
3. Choose `Code Spell Checker`
4. Click on reload button/Restart VSCode

Comment: Didn't work for me. VSCode version 1.66.2, vscode-spell-checker version v2.2.3. Still getting ' command not found': 
 "[Window Title]
Visual Studio Code
[Content]
Command 'Spell: Go to Next Spelling Issue' resulted in an error (command 'cSpell.goToNextSpellingIssue' not found)"

Comment: Helped a lot! Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Updated and reinstalled the plugin.
I was still getting 'command not found' errors.

- VSCode version 1.66.2
- vscode-spell-checker version v2.2.3.

Step 2. **What have worked** however is updating VSCODe (and the plugin with it):

- VSCode version to 1.81.1
- vscode-spell-checker version v2.20.5

Version: 1.81.1 (system setup),
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794,
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z,
Electron: 22.3.18,
ElectronBuildId: 22689846,
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215,
Node.js: 16.17.1,
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0,
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045.